# Make an isometric 3d game in vb.NET is too slow

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, 3d, isometric

So! I'm on an isometric 3d game in VB.Net, everything goes well. It works just like that:
There are bitmaps that represent each layer of the 3d map. Then the engine turn 'em in an array of arrays of strings, where G is grass block, W is water block... Without bitmap reading, works like that:

```
    Dim layer1() as string = {"GGGRR RG",
                              "RGG  W R",
                              ...}
    Dim layer2() as string = {...}
    Dim map() ... = {layer1,layer2...}
```

Then the engine has to draw it. And this is where I've got a few problems...

First, I've got three for loops that perfectly draw the map. Looks pretty good. First problem is the next : I wonder whether I shall draw onto my form or onto a pictureBox.

Next problem: I' m using e.graphics in paint event for drawing textures. When I try doing it in a timer, it goes extremely slow... 
So my solution was to draw the entire map just once and then use it as a bitmap on each timer iteration and then draw the hero onto the map, at right positions. Worked great, but when the player is behind a wall, it appears like it's in front of it because it can't be drawn before a part of the map because the map is already drawn. So my solution doesn't seem to work...

So I'd like to know how I can make graphics faster for drawing my map every time and what's the fastest drawer between pictureBox and form. Or if you got a better solution for me that stays in .NET, please tell me everything!

Comment: You could draw the layers to separate bitmaps which would allow occlusions. If you need something faster, you will likely need to switch so something hardware-accelerated (WPF, DirectX, OpenGL...). Also make sure to only draw in the Paint event of the controls.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your fast answer. But, I don't know those technologies, I just heard about them. So you really think it'going to be much faster? And which one of them shall I use? I thought WPF was just like winforms but I guess I was wrong. So just would like to know which one of what you said I shall learn. (Ps : I paint everything in Paint event, the problem is more about drawing kinda 210 bitmaps at each iteration. But I can reduce that number with what you told me, with the layers.)

Comment: The difference is that WinForms mostly uses the CPU to draw things and then sends the result to the graphics card for display (there are some exceptions, though). If you use any of the other technologies I mentioned, drawing happens directly on the graphics card, which is optimized for this task. And there is no need to transfer the result (WPF has some exceptions). Having the layers ready in an image is a good idea in any case. So I would only recommend switching technologies if it becomes a real bottleneck. The programming paradigms are quite different.